# how to program the raspberry pi using python to input analog values

Tags: python-3.x

i want to input the current and temperature values in raspberry pi3. i already have a ADC ADS1115 and able to figure out the electrical connections , but the programming part is bit difficult. can you guys help me ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow isn't the right place to look for a programming tutorial. If you can find basic info somewhere else and run into trouble implementing it, feel free to come back and ask us specific questions about your code and the issues you're having with it.

Answer (score 0):

see here [raspberry-pi-analog-to-digital-converters](https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-analog-to-digital-converters/ads1015-slash-ads1115)